# when I add google fonts dependency to pubspec I get strange error

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

when I add   `google_fonts: ^3.0.1` dependency to my pubspec.yaml file I get this strange error:

```
pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/david/daca/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.1.4".)
```

I upgraded my flutter but it's still happens

my flutter version is:

```
Flutter 3.7.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c07f788888 (4 days ago) • 2023-02-22 17:52:33 -0600
Engine • revision 0f359063c4
Tools • Dart 2.19.2 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

what could be the reason ?

Comment: run `open /Users/david/daca/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.1.4` cmd, and add the screenshot of finder.

Comment: The problem could be that you ran the 'pub get' command in the terminal with the path /Users/david/daca/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-2.1.4. While this should be the main directory of the project.